# html5 multiple submits in play framework

Tags: html, playframework, form-submit

I need to do something like this with the play framework 2.1:

```
@form(routes.PedidoCtrl.carregaTabela){
   //...
   <input type="submit" value="Page 1">
   <input type="submit" formaction="????" value="Page 2">
   <input type="submit" formaction="????" formmethod="post" value="Page 3">
}
```

But what should i put in the "formaction" field?
I've never used the "formaction" attribute, but i saw thar is what i want to do in this page: http://cbsa.com.br/post/formulario-com-multiplos-submit-e-method-em-html5.aspx (portuguese)

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had never seen that either but it seems extremely useful.

You would use the same reverse routing that you're already using on the `@form` helper. I modified your sample code. Obviously just replace "action2" and "action3" with whatever your other action methods are.

```
@form(routes.PedidoCtrl.carregaTabela){
  //...
  <input type="submit" value="Page 1">
  <input type="submit" formaction="@routes.PedidoCtrl.action2" value="Page 2">
  <input type="submit" formaction="@routes.PedidoCtrl.action3" formmethod="@routes.PedidoCtrl.action3.method" value="Page 3">
}
```

Note the `@` escape character in front of "routes.PedidoCtrl..."

The reverse routing returns a `play.api.mvc.Call` instance. That class has an `url()` method which is what is getting output for your `formaction` attribute (it's calling `toString` which in turn calls `url`). There's also the `method()` method which you can use for the `formmethod` attribute.